# Which Graph API should be used with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Does Microsoft Graph is started supporting B2C setup?

I found bunch of articles that says this feature is coming soon but all of them are dated more than a year.

I am assuming it might have started supporting by this time but I did not find any clue about it in the Microsoft Graph Documentation.

Does anybody know if it supporting B2C now?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ambiguous but it is clear from [the Azure AD B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) that "you must use the Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD B2C directory".